# How to convert "Tue Aug 25 10:00:00 2015" this time stamp to "2015-08-25 10:00" in python

Tags: python

How to convert `"Tue Aug 25 10:00:00 2015"` this time stamp to ‍‍`"2015-08-25        10:00"` in python.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

Answer (score 2):

With the correct format string, you can use `datetime.strptime` to parse the string and format it again:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue Aug 25 10:00:00 2015', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d        %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

use [parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) using `pip install python-dateutil`

```
>>>from dateutil import parser
>>>str(parser.parse("Tue Aug 25 10:00:00 2015"))
'2015-08-25 10:00:00'
```